# Unable to install Selenium WebDriver through command prompt

Tags: python, selenium, automation, webdriver

When I try to install Selenium WebDriver on cmd prompt using command "python setup.py install" I am getting error "The program can't start because api-ms-win-crt-runtime-Il-1-0.dll missing from your computer". I am using Python version-3.7 and I have set the path of the Python in environment variable. Please help me how to solve this issue, I am new to Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download [get-pip.py](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) to a directory in your computer.

Then run

```
python get-pip.py
```

Then do

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Then use this in your code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

Comment: I am getting error "No matching distribution found for install" after typing command "python get-pip.py"

Comment: Are you on MAC or Linux? What OS are you on?

Comment: I am using Windows 7

Comment: Okay, make sure the file you downloaded from the link I posted is actually a .py file. Check the file list in your command prompt. And make sure its py and not ending with txt. Secondly, make sure you have execute rights on that folder. Once that's confirmed, python get-pip.py should work. And make sure it's  Python 3.5 (64 bit).

Comment: I have installed python 3.7 version

Comment: Try this: python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Yes it solved the issue. But after writing code: from selenium import webdriver, I am getting error "Unresolved import: webdriver"

Comment: What IDE are you using? If PyDev, following should work. I'd suggest delete the old interpreters from Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters. And then create a new interpreter with the correct paths.

Comment: I am using pydev, Created a new interpreter, Still no success.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have Python installed in your computer, then you need only do this:

```
pip install selenium
```