# I am having problem to install webdrive module in python 3.6

Tags: python, selenium, module, pip, webdriver

I am having problems to install webdrive module

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update -y && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

and
i tried to install selenium and import webdrive from it and it didn't work
    form selenium import webdrive
keep and i get this error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'webdrive'
>
> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   webdrive (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found
>   for webdrive

Comment: have you installed selenium ? if selenium is installed you can import webdriver, no need to install.

Comment: i tried to install it and it didn't work

Comment: selenium ? what command you used to install ?

Comment: What are you trying to install. Please be more specific

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to install Selenium WebDriver through command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51726711/unable-to-install-selenium-webdriver-through-command-prompt)

Comment: Vikas P: pip3 install webdrive

Comment: Kostas Charitidis: iam trying to install webdrive module in python3.6

Comment: @AhmedAssal there is no webdrive module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to install webdriver. Because there is no such module.
First install `selenium` with this command:

```
pip3 install selenium
```

After that, you have to download webdriver and not install it.
Open this selenium page: https://pypi.org/project/selenium/ , scroll to the *Drivers* section and choose that the driver that you want according to your browser.

Place the driver in your python folder. If it doesn't work, then follow instructions according to the selenium page:

> *Selenium requires a driver to interface with the chosen browser. Firefox, for example, requires geckodriver, which needs to be installed before the below examples can be run. Make sure it’s in your PATH, e. g., place it in /usr/bin or /usr/local/bin.*
>
> *Failure to observe this step will give you an error selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: ‘geckodriver’ executable needs to be in PATH.*

Cheers